# "You are already subscribed to our newsletter" message

Tags: civimail, newsletter, subscribe

When someone who is already subscribed to our newsletter (i.e. they are a member of the relevant group) tries to subscribe to the newsletter again (for whatever reason, maybe the newsletters go to their Spam), nothing is happening that indicates that the person is already subscribed.

How can we make it so that in such a situation a message such as "You are already subscribed" would appear or, even better, the person gets redirected to a specified page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CiviCRM does not have this feature built-in. You would need to write a custom extension to achieve this, probably using [hook_civicrm_postProcess](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/hook_civicrm_postProcess).